# Having trouble distinguishing between players in URL for web scraping data from baseball-reference.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, url

```
def getURL(playerName):
    begURL = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/'
    names = playerName.split()
    letter = names[1][0].lower()
    midURL = begURL + letter + '/'
    lastAbr = names[1][0:5].lower()
    firstAbr = names[0][0:2].lower()
    URL = midURL + lastAbr + firstAbr + '01.shtml'
    return URL
```

This code is used to get the url from baseball reference based on a users input of player name. Sometimes this doesn't work, because there are multiple people with the same name or their name has changed. I am trying to allow uses to compare mlb players and choose either pitcher or batter.

For example, if you input Giancarlo Stanton, there is an error bc his name was Mike Stanton in the first two years of his career. While that is a minor problem that will not happen often, there are alot of players who have the same name, and therefore the URL should change at the end to 02 or 03... The scrap only works for getting a small amount of stats from 2022, so if it is an old player, the scrape doesnt work and their is an error.

Is there an easier way to account for this besides coding in everyones special URLs if they do not follow the basic URL pattern?

Comment: use `for`-loop to generate urls with different numbers - and check if you can load urls from server.

Comment: your url `https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/` shows list of all players so you can search your player on this page and get its URL.

Comment: page has field to search person - maybe you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use the player register and use the player ids. You can get the player ids from the sup_players_search_list.csv. Then it's just a matter of picking the guy you want.

I added a couple packages `fuzzywuzzy` and `choice` to do that. This will help in the event of typos, misspellings, etc. as well.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

#pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import process

#pip install choice
import choice



def askname():
    playerNameInput = input(str("Enter the player's name -> "))
    return playerNameInput


# Get all player IDs
player_df = pd.read_csv('https://www.baseball-reference.com/short/inc/sup_players_search_list.csv', header=None)
player_df = player_df.rename(columns={0:'id',
                                      1:'playerName',
                                      2:'years'})
playersList = list(player_df['playerName'])


# asks user for player name
playerNameInput = askname()


# Find closest matches
search_match = pd.DataFrame(process.extract(f'{playerNameInput}', playersList))
search_match = search_match.rename(columns={0:'playerName',1:'matchScore'})

matches = pd.merge(search_match, player_df, how='inner', on='playerName').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
choices = [': '.join(x) for x in list(zip(matches['playerName'], matches['years']))]

# Choice the match
playerChoice = choice.Menu(choices).ask()
playerName, years = playerChoice.split(': ')

# Get that match players id
match = player_df[(player_df['playerName'] == playerName) & (player_df['years'] == years)]

baseUrl = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.fcgi?id='
playerId = match.iloc[0]['id']

url = f'{baseUrl}{playerId}'



# Get the data
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tables_dict = {}
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for table in tables:
    stat_type = table.find('caption').text.strip()
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    
    tables_dict[stat_type] = df

for tableName, table in tables_dict.items():
    print(f'\n\n*** {tableName} ***')
    print(table.to_string())
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the player's name -> Giancarlo Stanton
Make a choice:
 0: Giancarlo Stanton: 2010-2022
 1: Tom Stanton: 1904
 2: Carl Husta: 1925
 3: Joe Staton: 1972-1973
 4: Carl Sitton: 1909

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 0
```

And the data:

```
*** Baseball America ***
          0    1
0  Pre-2009  #16
1  Pre-2010   #3


*** Baseball Prospectus ***
          0    1
0  Pre-2009  #14
1  Pre-2010   #5


*** Futures Game ***
                   0     1
0  2009 Futures Game  U.S.


*** Register Batting ***
                       Year                      Age  ...   SF  IBB
0                      2007                       17  ...    1    0
1                      2007                       17  ...    1    0
2                      2007                       17  ...    0    0
3                      2008                       18  ...    3    7
4                      2009                       19  ...    6    1
5                      2009                       19  ...    5    1
6                      2009                       19  ...    1    0
7                      2009                       19  ...    0    0
8                      2010                       20  ...    2   10
9                      2010                       20  ...    1    6
10                     2011                       21  ...    6    6
11                     2012                       22  ...    0    0
12                     2012                       22  ...    1    9
13                     2013                       23  ...    0    0
14                     2013                       23  ...    1    5
15                     2014                       24  ...    2   24
16                     2015                       25  ...    0    0
17                     2015                       25  ...    3    6
18                     2016                       26  ...    2    5
19                     2017                       27  ...    3   13
20                     2018                       28  ...   10    5
21                     2019                       29  ...    0    0
22                     2019                       29  ...    0    0
23                     2019                       29  ...    0    0
24                     2019                       29  ...    1    0
25                     2020                       30  ...    0    1
26                     2021                       31  ...    3    1
27                     2022                       32  ...    3    2
28                     Year                      Age  ...   SF  IBB
29      Majors (13 seasons)      Majors (13 seasons)  ...   36   83
30       Minors (8 seasons)       Minors (8 seasons)  ...   12   18
31         Other (1 season)         Other (1 season)  ...    0    0
32  All Levels (16 Seasons)  All Levels (16 Seasons)  ...   48  101
33                      NaN                      NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
34           AAA (1 season)           AAA (1 season)  ...    0    0
35           AA (2 seasons)           AA (2 seasons)  ...    7   11
36           A+ (5 seasons)           A+ (5 seasons)  ...    1    0
37             A (1 season)             A (1 season)  ...    3    7
38            A- (1 season)            A- (1 season)  ...    1    0
39            Rk (1 season)            Rk (1 season)  ...    0    0

[40 rows x 30 columns]


*** Register Fielding ***
                       Year                      Age  ... lgCS% PO.1
0                      2007                       17  ...   NaN  NaN
1                      2007                       17  ...   NaN  NaN
2                      2007                       17  ...   NaN  NaN
3                      2007                       17  ...   NaN  NaN
4                      2007                       17  ...   NaN  NaN
..                      ...                      ...  ...   ...  ...
76   All Levels (3 Seasons)   All Levels (3 Seasons)  ...   NaN  NaN
77    All Levels (1 Season)    All Levels (1 Season)  ...   NaN  NaN
78   All Levels (5 Seasons)   All Levels (5 Seasons)  ...   NaN  NaN
79  All Levels (14 Seasons)  All Levels (14 Seasons)  ...   NaN  NaN
80  All Levels (15 Seasons)  All Levels (15 Seasons)  ...   NaN  NaN

[81 rows x 26 columns]


*** Teams Played For ***
    Year  Age                                Tm  ... Stint        From          To
0   2007   17                       GCL Marlins  ...   NaN  2007-08-16  2007-08-27
1   2007   17                 Jamestown Jammers  ...   NaN  2007-08-29  2007-09-07
2   2008   18           Greensboro Grasshoppers  ...   NaN  2008-04-03  2008-09-01
3   2009   19               Jupiter Hammerheads  ...   NaN  2009-04-09  2009-06-03
4   2009   19                 Jacksonville Suns  ...   NaN  2009-06-05  2009-09-07
5   2009   19                    Mesa Solar Sox  ...   NaN  2009-10-13  2009-10-22
6   2010   20                 Jacksonville Suns  ...   NaN  2010-04-08  2010-06-05
7   2010   20                   Florida Marlins  ...   1.0  2010-06-08  2010-10-03
8   2011   21                   Florida Marlins  ...   1.0  2011-04-01  2011-09-28
9   2012   22                     Miami Marlins  ...   1.0  2012-04-04  2012-10-03
10  2012   22               Jupiter Hammerheads  ...   NaN  2012-08-02  2012-08-05
11  2013   23                     Miami Marlins  ...   1.0  2013-04-01  2013-09-29
12  2013   23               Jupiter Hammerheads  ...   NaN  2013-06-04  2013-06-09
13  2014   24                     Miami Marlins  ...   1.0  2014-03-31  2014-09-11
14  2015   25                     Miami Marlins  ...   1.0  2015-04-06  2015-06-26
15  2015   25               Jupiter Hammerheads  ...   NaN  2015-09-01  2015-09-01
16  2016   26                     Miami Marlins  ...   1.0  2016-04-05  2016-10-02
17  2017   27                     Miami Marlins  ...   1.0  2017-04-03  2017-10-01
18  2018   28                  New York Yankees  ...   1.0  2018-03-29  2018-09-29
19  2019   29                  New York Yankees  ...   1.0  2019-03-28  2019-09-29
20  2019   29                     Tampa Tarpons  ...   NaN  2019-05-20  2019-06-12
21  2019   29  Scranton/Wilkes-Barre RailRiders  ...   NaN  2019-06-14  2019-06-16
22  2020   30                  New York Yankees  ...   1.0  2020-07-23  2020-09-26
23  2021   31                  New York Yankees  ...   1.0  2021-04-01  2021-10-03
24  2022   32                  New York Yankees  ...   1.0  2022-04-08  2022-05-24

[25 rows x 9 columns]
```